# Undefined method on custom has_many with source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Run.rb:
  has_many :schedule_machines, through: :schedule_locations

Schedule.rb:
  has_many :schedule_locations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :schedule_machines, through: :schedule_locations
  has_many :assigned_schedule_machines, through: :runs, source: :schedule_machines
  has_many :runs, dependent: :destroy
```

when I look at a Schedule in the console,

```
schedule.assigned_schedule_machines
```

gives an undefined method.

How come?

Comment: could you add the code that creates this `schedule` instance, also the error stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
has_many :runs, dependent: :destroy
has_many :assigned_schedule_machines, through: :runs, source: :schedule_machines
```

You need to order the "runs" first. The assigned_schedule wants to use runs; but in your original code the runs wasn't defined yet.